# How to do a split background in tailwinds

Tags: tailwind-css

I know I can do it in CSS with linear-gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 50%, #f3f4f6 50%, #f3f4f6 100% )
```

But I can not make it work in Tailwindcss `(#f3f4f6 is bg-gray-100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`background-image` arbitrary value class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values) like:

```html
<div class="… bg-[image:linear-gradient(to_right,white_0%,white_50%,#f3f4f6_50%,#f3f4f6_100%)]">
```

Alternatively, you could [add the gradient as a value in your Tailwind configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme) like:

```html
<div class="… bg-foo">
```

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        foo: 'linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 50%, #f3f4f6 50%, #f3f4f6 100%)',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Also, you could set `--tw-gradient-stops` that Tailwind uses "behind the scenes" for its gradient classes (though I feel like this is more an internal implementation and is not intended for public use):

```html
<div class="… bg-gradient-to-r [--tw-gradient-stops:to_right,white_0%,white_50%,#f3f4f6_50%,#f3f4f6_100%]">
```

All examples:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        foo: 'linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 50%, #f3f4f6 50%, #f3f4f6 100%)',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<div class="h-40 w-40 bg-[image:linear-gradient(to_right,white_0%,white_50%,#f3f4f6_50%,#f3f4f6_100%)]"></div>

<div class="h-40 w-40 bg-foo"></div>

<div class="h-40 w-40 bg-gradient-to-r [--tw-gradient-stops:to_right,white_0%,white_50%,#f3f4f6_50%,#f3f4f6_100%]"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to be able to achieve the effect with native TW classes but I will go with the tailwind configuration option.